# Many-to-Many Relation with CoreData

Tags: core-data

[image: Relation]

Hallo,

I have the datamodel in the picture. But I need the following model.

When I add a damage report `Damage`, this report should relate to one or many `Address` objects from the stored addresses in the datastore.

Every `Address` should also added only once to the datastore.

How should I define the relationship between `Address` and `Damage`?

**Damage:**
[image: Damage]

**Address:**
[image: Address]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the relationship between `Damage` and `Address` many to many. Select the `damage` relationship of `Address` in the model editor, and switch the type from To One to To Many.

The word "damage" is not a countable noun. A better choice for that entity name would be `DamageReport` or `DamageIncident`.

As for having a unique `Address` entity for each address, you'll have to enforce that yourself, with code. Core Data cannot do this for you. Choose which attributes of the `Address` entity make it unique: probably `street` and `zipcode`. Then write a method that accepts street, zipcode, and managed object context, and searches Core Data for an `Address` object matching those parameters. That method will return the existing object, if any, or will create a new one, populated with street and zipcode, and return it to you for the rest of the initialization. This pattern is commonly called "find or create", and is documented in Apple's Core Data programming guide.